# macOS TeamCity Build Agent won't upgrade

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-10

I have just setup TeamCity for the first time, and am trying to connect a macOS Build Agent so I can use the Xcode Project build step. However, after installing the agent on a Mac, it connects to my server, I authorised it but it just keeps getting stuck trying to upgrade.

See the logs below:

```html
[2016-12-30 18:43:38,909]   WARN - .agent.AmazonPropertiesUpdater - Fetched Amazon EC2 instance metadata does not contain required values. Probably this agent was not started inside Amazon EC2. Is proxy server used?
[2016-12-30 18:43:39,200]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server via URL http://server:8111. AgentDetails{Name='macOS-agent', AgentId=null, BuildId=null, AgentOwnAddress='null', AlternativeAddresses=[192.168.1.100], Port=9090, Version='42538', PluginsVersion='NA', AvailableRunners=[], AvailableVcs=[], AuthorizationToken='309dfc276322e9032f1b8dd10c36d1a1', PingCode='PTlCyAKlgWHkzLTXeSMYSo5fk1PBujzq'}
[2016-12-30 18:43:39,662]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Server supports the following communication protocols: [polling, xml-rpc]
[2016-12-30 18:43:39,662]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Trying to register on server using 'polling' protocol.
[2016-12-30 18:43:39,986]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registered on server with id 1 and authorization token '309dfc276322e9032f1b8dd10c36d1a1'
[2016-12-30 18:43:39,986]   INFO - buildServer.AGENT.registration - If this is the first time this agent registered on the server make sure it is authorized by administrator in the server web UI.
Upgrade call received from the build server
Will upgrade when become idle
```

It isn't doing anything else, but just seems to be stuck on waiting to become 'idle' forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being left 'idle' for around 40 minutes, the process started and finished a few minutes later.

So the solution for this is to just be patient!